# Playing multiple tracks in sync flash builder

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I'm about to create some art installation using augmented reality and music. I'd like to implement some kind of sampler in it, but I can't find any way to do it.

It's gonna be a looper, I've got 12 files (each 8 seconds) and I want to play them synchronized - so they must start at the same time. this is example of something similiar to my project: http://www.incredibox.fr/ . They must be controlled by changing volume (0 means off).

When I'm adding them to the code and play - delay is very annoying. Is there any posibility to sync them?

Comment: Is this a Flash or Flex application?

Comment: flash, I'm using actionscript 3 no controls on screen are needed

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript 3 uses the notion of *Cue Points* for synchronization.

**Using Cue Points:** http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000561.html

This enables the coordination of playback with events. NetStream events can then be used to control and coordinate your loops at specific points.

**NetStream Events:** http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#eventSummary